# MediaPlayer stops playing music from the internet after few minutes in sleep-mode

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, sleep-mode

I have Android App which plays music from URL, but when my telephone goes to sleep-mode it plays 5 mins and then stops playing if I unlock my device its continue playing.

I've tried this [Playing music in sleep/standby mode in Android 2.3.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13361280/playing-music-in-sleep-standby-mode-in-android-2-3-3) solution but it not helped.

Also, I've tried to use *startForegroundService()* but it can be used only on android 8 and higher. But my projects minimal version is android 5.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public static Srting src = "http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4";
public void Play(View view){
        startService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
        play.setEnabled(false);
    }
```

**MyService.java**

```
public class MyService extends Service {
    MediaPlayer ambientMediaPlayer;
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {

        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(){
        ambientMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        ambientMediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
        ambientMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    }
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId){
        try {
            ambientMediaPlayer.setDataSource(MainActivity.src);
            ambientMediaPlayer.prepare();
            ambientMediaPlayer.start();
        }catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return START_STICKY;
    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        ambientMediaPlayer.stop();
    }
}
```

Comment: which Android version you are running?

Comment: @Naveen Android 8.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `startService`, if you are targeting android oreo and above. You have to use `startForeground` or `startForegroundService`. See this post https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/target-sdk#prenougat. so try below example.

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
       startForegroundService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
    } else {
        startService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! But if someone start my application in android lower than Oreo, they whould have the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it is a bug [START_STICKY does not work on Android KitKat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20636330/start-sticky-does-not-work-on-android-kitkat) .

Comment: Clear, ok would use android 5 as the minimal sdk, but it is not solution for my question